# How do I exit my current branch?

Tags: git, version-control

I have cloned a repository and created a branch (`branch1`) off it.
I have a few changes in that branch.
Now I want to exit this branch, and create a new branch off of `master`.

From what I understand, I can create a new branch using `git branch myBranch`, 
then switch to the branch by `git checkout myBranch`.
But won't doing this create a new branch off the existing branch `branch1`?

I want to exit my current branch (`branch1`) and then create a new branch and enter it (`myBranch`)
How can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do a 
`git checkout master`.
Then a
`git checkout -b new_branch`

`git checkout -b foo` is the short form for `git branch foo` and `git checkout foo` afterwards.

Note that uncommitted changes will be still there on the new branch. If you have any conflicts because the files on master changed in the meantime, you can use `git stash` to stash your current changes, checkout your new branch and do a `git stash apply` afterwards. You need to resolve occuring conflicts on the new branch then.

Answer (score 1):

From the `git branch manual` documentation:

**SYNOPSIS**

> git branch [--set-upstream | --track | --no-track] [-l] [-f] < branchname > [< start-point >]

**DESCRIPTION**

> The command [...] creates a new branch head named < branchname > which points to the current HEAD, or < start-point > if given.
>   Note that this will create the new branch, but it will not switch the working tree to it; use "git checkout " to switch to the new branch.

Thus, `git branch myBranch master` will create a new branch starting from the commit to which the current `master` branch head refers to.
In order to work on the freshly created branch, run `git checkout myBranch`. 
This is kinda the long form for `git checkout -b myBranch master`.

For a more detailed description, read through [doc git-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) and [doc git-checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, to switch from a branch to a *new* branch with zero changes, you can do the following

```
# to discard not committed changes for ever
git reset --hard HEAD
# In case you don't want to discard change but put them aside for now
git stash --all

# to switch to the new branch which is created and placed on the <commit_reference>
git checkout -b <new_branch_name> <commit_reference>
```

However you should explain further what you mean when you say *exit* a branch, remove it? or just switch to another branch.
If you want to remove it, you need to run this after the two previous commands

```
 git branch -d <branch_you_exited>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use only one command to meet your requirement, that is

**`git checkout -b myBranch commit`**

The functions of the command are:

1.Exit current branch.

2.Create a new branch myBranch (`git branch myBranch`) from the commit you specified.

3.Switch myBranch as current branch (`git checkout myBranch`).

#### e.g.

`git checkout -b myBranch be42c57`, git create a new branch myBranch from `be42c57` and point HEAD to it.

`git checkout -b myBranch master`, git will create a new branch myBranch from master (the latest commit id on master) and point HEAD to it.

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late , you might have figured it, still to complete the thread here is the command you need to switch to main or switch to master ( just to return from where you created the branch) -

git checkout -

You can read more here - https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/git-switch-branch/

Comment: Well as you point switch command, probably you should use it in your answer as well. checkout command does so many things that people get confused with it, better use switch